# Convert columns of text

Tags: python, text

I have a text file containing a format like below (I have put part of the text file). It has four columns. The third and fourth columns are the name of jpg files. For example, the third and fourth column in the first row are the first frame and last frame which has the associated value of `83` in the second column.

So it represents as series in a way that third and fourth column are kind of the first and last value of the series. I want to convert this text file in a way that it includes the frames in between as well. I included what I want in below.

Since I am not good with python whatever I did, I failed. How I can do this in python?

```
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000001 000177
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000178 000218
```

What I want:

```
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000001
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000002
...
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000117
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1  000178
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1  000179
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Using CSV module to parse input, but write txt output

> Input: file data.txt (assume space between each field)
>
> Output: file result.txt

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as infile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ') # assume space between each field
    for row in readCSV:
        if row: # skip blank rows
            for i in range(int(row[2]), int(row[3])+1):
                # number of loops based upon values in columns 2 & 3
                # Create output string
                result = "{} {} {:06d}".format(row[0], row[1], i)
                outfile.write(result + "\n")
```

**Output**

results.txt file

```
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000001
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000002
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000003
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000004
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000005
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000006
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000007
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000008
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000009
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000010
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000011
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response however, the third (last) column of output file is not as it should be!

Comment: @user8034918--forgot your third column has leading zeros.  Simple change.  Is this correct now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module to parse the values ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wZMCnj/1)) and then string formatting to get your output:

```
data = '''Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000001 000177
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000178 000218'''

import re

for val, _from, _to in re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d+)\s+(\d+)$', data, flags=re.M):
    for i in range(int(_from), int(_to) + 1):
        print('{}{:0{width}d}'.format(val, i, width=len(_from)))
```

Prints:

```
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000001
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000002
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000003
...
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000176
Sub01/Scn1/Clr/rgb1 83 000177
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000178
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000179
...
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000216
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000217
Sub02/Scn4/Clr/rgb1 1 000218
```

---

EDIT: To load the variables from file you can use this example (the `template.txt` contains string in format from your question):

```
import re

with open('template.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if line.strip() == '':    # skip empty lines
            continue
        for val, _from, _to in re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d+)\s+(\d+)$', line.strip()):
            for i in range(int(_from), int(_to) + 1):
                print('{}{:0{width}d}'.format(val, i, width=len(_from)), file=f_out)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response but it didn't work! I have a large text file and I had put only part of it here. So I want to read the text file and I did it and it failed. I read the text file like `data = open("template.txt","r")`

Comment: With your new edit, I am getting this message: `WARNING: some intermediate output was truncated.
WARNING: 159 intermediate output messages were discarded.` Is it possible to output a text file instead?

Comment: @user8034918 yes, I edited my answer. now it produces `output.txt` instead printing on the screen.